# Page width is higher/bigger than content width html/css What am I doing wrong?

Tags: html, css

So the problem [is the following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukDFu.jpg):

My content width is higher than the screen width, but unfortunately I have no idea why.

My HTML is the following:

[HTML](http://pastebin.com/gRNkZbww)

And my two css files

[CSS](http://pastebin.com/EzLphj9E) - general

[CSS](http://pastebin.com/KAt14vAu) - airbnb

The weird thing is when I am inspecting the element, the bod and html seem to have the correct width.

What am I doing wrong ? There's a twig statement in the html file, you can just remove it if you don't have Twig installed.

Thank you for your help

PS: If it helps, the background image from the css is s17.postimg.org/ik3jnp9cv/background.jpg

Comment: Paste your code here so that easily analysis can be performed on your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this in your body in the airbnb_main.css file

```
 background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
```

and do:

```
.search_container {
  position: relative;
    top: 145px;
    left: 20%;
   /*right: 0;*/
max-width: 80%;
 }
```

Comment: it was because you pushed the <div class="form-group search_container"> 210px from the left and it did stay 100% of the width what means it goes out of the background , with 20% left and 80% width it will always stay 100% so that will not happen anymore

Comment: You are right. Thank you !!